# How to access a control in another c# applications?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to let me get the tag attribute of one TreeNode object in another c# application?

It is easy to get the handle of the TreeNode, but how to continue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to get tag value at runtime?

Comment: yes. The target application has been launched already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, without cooperation from the Application with the TreeView it is not possible.

The Tag property is part of the managed class that is attached to the TreeNode-control. You can only get at the Win32 part of the control when you have the handle. The managed part is in an address-space where you have no access.

Comment: OK, thanks. It avoids me to spend more efforts to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Expose a WCF service or a remoting service from one application, if possible.

Comment: Thanks. But the target c# application is not owned by me. SO I have no chance to add service in it ... ...

Comment: @Meng: Sorry, I can't help with that.